# Sidekiq jobs not queueing on rails app deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I have a rails app using sidekiq, sidekiq-status, and sidekiq batching:

```
gem "sidekiq"
gem "sidekiq-status"
# freemium version vs sidekiq pro https://github.com/breamware/sidekiq-batch
gem "sidekiq-batch"
# slim & sinatra for sidekiq monitoring
gem "sinatra", "2.0.0.beta2", require: nil
```

Locally when I run sidekiq and redis, the jobs process.
When deployed to heroku, the jobs are queued but they do not process.

I am using the Rediscloud and have the env variable `REDIS_PROVIDER` set to `REDISCLOUD_URL` and both `REDISCLOUD_URL` and `REDIS_URL` set to the generated url from the Rediscloud addon.

Procfile:

```
high_worker: DB_POOL=$SIDEKIQ_DB_POOL bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY -t 8 -q high
default_worker: DB_POOL=$SIDEKIQ_DB_POOL bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY -t 8 -q default
low_worker: DB_POOL=$SIDEKIQ_DB_POOL bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY -t 8 -q low
```

When I startup a queue manually on heroku, ie `heroku run DB_POOL=10 bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -t 8 -q low -a {my_app_name}`, the queue processes those jobs.

What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: Are those workers scaled up, and / or are you running them as scheduled jobs?

Comment: hi! I have tried both scheduled jobs and scaled up workers. Currently if I console into heroku and start an async job on any of the queues, it gets added to the queue but is never processed.

Comment: And if you run [`heroku ps`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-type-type) after scaling the dynos, it shows them running?

Comment: Huh, that is interesting, no I do not see them running then. What do I do specifically to scale them up? If I run `heroku run DB_POOL=10 bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -t 8 -q low -a {my_app_name}` to scale them manually, it works and shows when I run `heroku ps`. Maybe I am not understand the process correctly. Shouldn't the Procfile start those processes? Why might it not be? Thanks so much.

Comment: Disclaimer, I'm not a Rails guy but I know Heroku reasonably well. Should `bundle exec sidekiq...` start a process that runs continually, or does it process the queue and then stop running? In any case, to scale your dynos you'd typically use [`heroku ps:scale`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-scale), e.g. `heroku ps:scale low_worker=1` for one dyno running the `low_worker` process. That should scale that process type up or down, as applicable, so one dyno is running it.

Comment: hey! @Chris thanks so much, silly me I thought that my CI/CD process was automatically starting/scaling the workers but I guess not. After scaling those up, the jobs are run.

Comment: Great! I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Procfile` *defines* process types, but it doesn't make them run.

Each process type can run on zero or more dynos. To change the number of dynos for each process type you can use [the `heroku ps:scale` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-scale). For example, to scale your `low_worker` process type to one dyno you can do

```
heroku ps:scale low_worker=1
```

Running dynos cost money and / or consume free dyno hours, so budget accordingly.

Alternatively, you can have your jobs [run at scheduled times via the Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduling-jobs). This is less appropriate for tasks that should run continuously, but it's an option.

Comment: this worked! turns out I was assuming my CI/CD process would scale these up for me, but that assumption was incorrect.